# How to add join subqueries

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following sql query that I'm trying to add to JPA repository

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM recipient r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT m.id, MAX(m.created_at)
    FROM message m INNER JOIN thread t
    ON t.id = m.thread_id
    WHERE t.id=19
) th
ON th.id = r.message_id
WHERE r.recipient_id = 12
```

I converted the query as follows

```java
@Repository
public interface RecipientJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<RecipientModel, Long> {
    @Query(
        "SELECT 1 \n"+
        "FROM RecipientModel r \n"+
        "INNER JOIN ( \n"+
        "   SELECT m.id, MAX(m.createdAt) \n"+
        "   FROM MessageModel m INNER JOIN ThreadModel t \n"+
        "   ON t.id = m.threadId \n"+
        "   WHERE t.id=19 \n"+
        ") th \n"+
        "ON th.id = r.messageId \n"+
        "WHERE r.recipientId = 12 "
    )
    int isRecipientOfThread();
}
```

When running, application stops due to syntax error near `(` bracket of the inner join.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 3, column 12 [SELECT 1 

INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT m.id, MAX(m.createdAt) 
    FROM fi.mediconsult.omasagamicroservicemessage.model.MessageModel m INNER JOIN fi.mediconsult.omasagamicroservicemessage.model.ThreadModel t 
    ON t.id = m.threadId 
    WHERE t.id=19
```

How can I add a query as the inner join?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to check that a message is the most recently created in the thread, but in fact the message id returned from the subquery will be some arbitrary one; the max() has no effect on which id is selected

Answer (score 1):

SubQueries in from clause are not allowed in JPA and HQL.

These are the available possibilities.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-subqueries.html